# When did equality metamethods change?

Tags: lua

There seems to be a change in the way equality metamethods are executed, but I cannot find the documentation in any of the 5.1, [5.2](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8) or [5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8) reference manuals (under the Change in the Language sections under Incompatabilities)

```
t1a = {}
t1b = {}
t2  = {}
mt1 = { __eq = function( o1, o2 ) return 'whee' end }
mt2 = { __eq = function( o1, o2 ) return 'whee' end }

setmetatable( t1a, mt1 )
setmetatable( t1b, mt1 )
setmetatable( t2,  mt2 )

print( t1a == t1b )     --> true
print( t1a == t2 )      --> false
```

from (http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents) and tested to be true on local 5.1.5 implementation

In Lua 5.3 running this actually yields

```
true
true
```

Executing from (https://www.lua.org/demo.html)

Is this a bug? Do metamethods for equality no longer have to be the same reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Lua expert, but comparing the [5.2 docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4):

> "eq": the == operation. The function getequalhandler defines how Lua chooses a metamethod for equality. A metamethod is selected only when both values being compared have the same type and **the same metamethod** for the selected operation, and the values are either tables or full userdata.

and the [5.3 docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4):

> __eq: the equal (==) operation. Behavior similar to the addition operation, except that Lua will try a metamethod only when the values being compared are either both tables or both full userdata and they are not primitively equal. The result of the call is always converted to a boolean.

the 5.3 docs list no requirement that the operands have the same metamethod.

Comment: This feels like a breaking change

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the kind of thing that should have gone on the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the source code on the Lua website right, this changed between Lua 5.2 and 5.3.

In Lua 5.2, if a pair of tables or userdata are not equal by reference, the equality of the two `__eq` metamethods was checked in [`luaV_equalobj_`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#luaV_equalobj) (using [`get_equalTM`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#get_equalTM), where TM stands for "tag method", the old name for metamethods), and only then would the metamethod be used. (In 5.1 the process is similar, but the methods are called [`luaV_equalval`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lvm.c.html#luaV_equalval) and [`lua_getcompTM`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lvm.c.html#get_compTM).) In 5.3, [`luaV_equalobj`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lvm.c.html#luaV_equalval) looks for an `__eq` metamethod in the first operand and then in the second operand; if any metamethod was found, it is called.

There was a discussion about this on the Lua list in 2015: [*Lua 5.3 changes to .__eq*](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2015-07/msg00204.html) ([easier-to-read Nabble version](http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Lua-5-3-changes-to-eq-td7668468.html)).